# When root user changes a table name, how to ensure end user permissions also gets updated to the new table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a table - `user1_db.table1`

user1 has the following permission -

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON `user1_db`.`table1` TO `user1`@`localhost`
```

Now the `root user` changes the table name to `table2`

But the permissions of `user1` still remains on the non-existent table - `table1` and not the new renamed table - `table2`

So, when `user1` tries to perform any of the above operations, it gets `access denied` error.

So is there a way to ensure that when `root user` changes table name, the permissions of all `end users` automatically gets updated to the new table name as well?

Comment: Either your "root user" is a clinical idiot, or he will not rename the table without finding and making all the necessary corrections related to this renaming.

Comment: @Akina But that's not that an answer :-) I just create a hypothetical scenario to see if any solution is possible

Comment: MySQL have no either DDL triggers or built-in indirect references checking mechanisms. So the only solution is "Look carefully what your hands do".